# Необходимо раскрутить тизерную сеть

Tags: seo, php

Есть тизерная сеть. Как ее лучше раскрутить при минимальном бюджете?

Comment: Соц сети только наверно. Больше способов не знаю...Сео я думаю тут бесполезно...Не? :). А вообще контекст...

Comment: интересен бюджет.

Answer (score 1):

Для продвижения **любого сайта**, в вашем случае - тизерной сети, **вы можете:**

**1.** Использовать силу *социальных сетей*, как подметил **Darix**.

**2.** *Воспользоваться форумами и сайтами этой тематики:* укажите адрес своей тизерной сети в своём профиле; общайтесь с пользователями форумов и рассказывайте им о своём проекте. Если ваша сеть будет действительно удобной и нужной, сработает *сарафанное радио*.

**3.** Если же рассматривать **платные варианты**, то самый дешёвый метод - *контекстная реклама*.